# How to update assembly info automatically

Tags: c#, version, assemblyinfo

I have a solution having 5 .NET projects. Is there a way to automate the version update in the form 1.0.* ?

Comment: The point of using "1.0.*" is that you don't have to automate it.

Answer (score 0):

You need the [AssemblyInfo Task](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/AssemblyInfoTaskvers) for that.

You can also use [VersionUpdator](http://testdox.wordpress.com/versionupdater/).

> VersionUpdater is a simple command line tool for .NET developers to
>   automatically increment version numbers when building .NET assemblies
>   from Visual Studio or your automated build scripts.

Answer (score 0):

[assembly: AssemblyVersion("2.02.*")]

Answer (score 0):

You can find below article helpful:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31236/How-To-Update-Assembly-Version-Number-Automaticall